# Hibernate MappingException on related secondary table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have situation where I would like to reference the first and last name of the user who has updated a task object. This should be a straight forward retrieval but Hibernate is not wiring the associations like I expect. Here are the object definitions:

```
Task Object:
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASKS")
public class TaskBean {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserBean.class, optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="MODIFIED_BY", referencedColumnName="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    public User getUser()
    ...



User Object:
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_")
@SecondaryTable(name="LOCAL_USER", 
        pkJoinColumns={
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PORTAL_USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USERID")})

public class UserBean {
    private BigDecimal userId; // USERID
    private String firstName; // FIRSTNAME
    private String lastName; // LASTNAME
    private String employeeId; // EMPLOYEE_ID

 ....

    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", table="LOCAL_USER", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    public String getEmployeeId() {
         return employeeId;
    }
```

The problem is with the @ManyToOne definition on TaskBean. When I try to run a unit test against TaskBeans I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: EMPLOYEE_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(USER_) and its related supertables and secondary tables

This doesn't make sense to me as I've clearly defined the EMPLOYEE_ID field within UserBean. Is it not possible to do this since that field is coming from a secondary table? The error message makes it sound like this is a reasonable thing to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the version of Hibernate you're using?

Comment: Hibernate Core 3.6.9.Final , Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final. I tried upgrading Commons Annotations to the latest version (3.3.0) as well but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

as described on Hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7713

you can apply workaround using gave accents to identify your referencedColumnName `

```
SecondaryTable(name="LOCAL_USER", 
    pkJoinColumns={
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PORTAL_USER_ID", referencedColumnName="`USERID`")})
```